# ASP.net Routes Static Route and Static File

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Website needs to have a url of www.siteurl.com/file.pdf

It will only every be this filename. It is printed on many of our publications as a quick reference. I need people to have direct access to the pdf file when they type this url.

I'm trying to use MVC Routes and I am having no success.  I must be overlooking something.

Comment: I didn't post my attempt because it was embarrassing to say the least.  I really need to know the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is actually at the root of the site, you do not need routing. Much like you do not have to define routes for your css, script files and images. Out of the box routing with that file in the root of your site will work fine. Static files will return if you have the proper path to them in the URL.

Comment: I simply had some typos and of course was trying to over-complicate MVC as usual. I merely linked directly to the file and everything worked. Thanks